# Errors while trying to "Put" JSON Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, put, hubspot

I am working with the Hubspot API and I am trying to modify the close date of a deal via the  "PUT" Method by sending JSON Data. But I am getting errors such as

> { status: 'error',   message: 'Invalid input JSON on line 1, column
>   15: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of
>   START_OBJECT token',   correlationId:
>   'b8b47229-184d-40b3-b402-9e3dd684b217',   requestId:
>   'd364fe8dac5e876639928dd0d04045fd' }

This is the code that I have written-

```
fetch('https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/103361780?hapikey=', {
  method: 'put',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"properties":{name: "closedate", "value": 1528744207881}})
}).then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

This is the JSON Data that I am trying to pass

```
 {
  "properties":[
    {

  "name": "closedate",
  "value": 1528744207881
    }
  ]
};
```

And [here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/deals/update_deal) is the documentation of making a PUT request via the Hubspot API.
I am able to successfully update the value via POSTMAN.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing brackets - [] and on the backend, they are waiting for an array to deserialize it to Arraylist.

Try fetch with this body:

```
{"properties":[{"name": "closedate", "value": 1528744207881}]}
```